# Airflow 1.10 version suddenly stopped sending alerts

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, alerts, airflow-webserver

I have been using airflow 1.10 since 3 years and even though there are no configuration changes happened recently, failed dags are not alerting the specified mailids.
WHat could be the reason for not alerting?

Answer (score 1):

Your software is 3 years after End of Life (at least - if we are talking about 1.10.15). It's not 3 years old. It's 3 years since it was officially announced as "End-Of-Life, no more fixes, no more security updates, please upgrade to Airflow 2 as soon as possible".

This means that any other software that it works with or is based on has not been updated for 3 years already. Including all security fixes. Python versions and OS that it was working on has largely reached EOL and it has never been touched to work with newer versions of those.

ALL KINDS of things might get wrong in this situations. Including you've been hacked by someone exploiting 1000s of vulnerabilities in Airflow, one of the 600 libraries it uses or any of the OS libraries you run it on.

Upgrade. NOW.